# Access to ethereum-wallet.net blocked by the owner

Tags: wallets

The link https://ethereum-wallet.net/ will not give me access to my ethereum wallet. The owner claims it has been hacked and blocked access. My Ethereum coins are still in my wallet I believe but I can't get to my wallet to move them.

I have my wallet code and I know my password. Is there any way I can get to my wallet?

Comment: A note to anyone else reading this: ethereum-wallet.net is in no way related to the Ethereum Wallet software, nor is ethereum-wallet.net run by the Ethereum Foundation. I've edited the headline accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

If you have your public and private key, you can enter them in another wallet tool to get at your funds (like [MyEtherWallet](https://www.myetherwallet.com/#send-transaction)).

If your "wallet code" is not actually the private key for your wallet, you'll have to wait for further updates from the ethereum-wallet.net owner to see what is the status of your funds.

Comment: Is there a way to identify if my wallet code is my private key? There is concern the owner may have stolen the Eth coins and therefore he will not be providing any assistance. I do not want to draw his attention to my wallet if the owner is the alleged thief. I just want a way to move my Eth coins from my current wallet to a new wallet.

Comment: I'm not familiar with what "ethereum-wallet" was using for their "wallet code", so not sure. An Ethereum private key is a 64-character hex string. If what you have as a "wallet code" is 64 hex characters, it might be the private key.

Comment: Any chance we can Skype so you can take a look at my ethereum account to see if there is a way for me to access my coins?